What causes the Property does not exist on type error in this Angular 16 movies app?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
I run into a problem while working on displaying a movie's details.
In app\services\movie-service.service.ts I have:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MovieResponse } from '../models/Movie';
import { Genre, GenreResponse } from '../models/Genre';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  public getLatestMovies(): Observable<MovieResponse> {
    return this.http.get<MovieResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/now_playing?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }

  public getMovieDetails(id: Number): Observable<MovieResponse>{
    return this.http.get<MovieResponse>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/${id}?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }
}

In app\models\Movie.ts I have:
export interface Movie {
    id?: number;
    adult?: boolean;
    backdrop_path?: string;
    poster_path?: string;
    title?: string;
    original_title?: string;
    tagline?: string;
    overview?: string;
    genre_ids?: any;
    release_date?: string;
    runtime?: number;
    vote_average?: string;
}

export interface MovieResponse {
    results?: Movie[];
    total_pages?: number;
    total_results?: number;
    page?: number;
}

In app\components\movie-details\movie-details.component.ts I have:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieResponse, Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-details',
  templateUrl: './movie-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-details.component.scss']
})
export class MovieDetailsComponent {

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse;
  public movie_id: Number = 0;

  public showMovieDetails() {
    this.movie_id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

    this.movieService.getMovieDetails(this.movie_id).subscribe((response) => {
      this.movieResponse = response;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showMovieDetails();
  }
}

In app\components\movie-details\movie-details.component.html I try to display the movie's title:
<div *ngIf="movieResponse">
  <h1>{{ movieResponse?.original_title }}</h1>
</div>

The problem
Insted of the desired result, I get this error in the browser:
TS2339: Property 'original_title' does not exist on type 'MovieResponse'.

Questions

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?


Your interface doesn't have original_title in MovieResponse, it is in the Movie interface. Your referencing the wrong interface.

I think return this.http.get<MovieResponse> needs to be return this.http.get<Movie> in your getMovieDetails() function.

This property 'original_title' does not exist on interface 'MovieResponse', exist on interface 'Movie'
so you must change this line:
  public movieResponse!: MovieResponse;

to :
  public movieResponse!: Movie;

and update the service:
  public getMovieDetails(id: Number): Observable<Movie>{
    return this.http.get<Movie>(`${environment.apiUrl}/movie/${id}?api_key=${environment.apiKey}`);
  }


Please try giving an answer to this question too.
